# selected item text in list box becomes trimmed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list box with bootstrap and multiple selection enabled.

The problem is when an option with long text(horizontal scroll is enabled) is selected,the selected option text is truncated to the width of the control (excluding the scroll size).

```html
<select class="form-control" style="overflow-x: auto;" multiple>
  <option>short text1</option>
  <option>These visual representations can convey a vast amount of non-text content. In addition to a short text equivalent, for many data images it may be necessary to provide more detailed information or supplemental content in the form of a long text alternative</option>
  <option>Complex data images include: charts, graphs, and diagrams. They allow sighted users to understand data and data relationships.</option>
</select>
```

[Taste me](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/35419/)

Is it possible for the selection not to be trimmed ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want it to wrap?

Comment: Add this to css.  select option{
  padding:5px;
}

Comment: I think you should rather question, whether for such amounts of text a select field is the best (no pun intended) option to begin with. Having to scroll such options in that direction feels like it might be rather terrible UX. A solution using checkboxes or radio buttons might be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Teammate solved the issue by adding the following CSS

```
select > option {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/42194/)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to hack around and get it to work:

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

select.form-control {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-row;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

select.form-control option {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<select class="form-control" multiple>
  <option>short text1</option>
  <option>These visual representations can convey a vast amount of non-text content. In addition to a short text equivalent, for many data images it may be necessary to provide more detailed information or supplemental content in the form of a long text alternative</option>
  <option>Complex data images include: charts, graphs, and diagrams. They allow sighted users to understand data and data relationships.</option>
</select>
```

I don't think this is perfect and the hack I put together might have some other issues that I'm not aware of (eg, `sizes` attribute is not playing nicely) but if you *absolutely must* use `select` to do your job, maybe this'll do for now. Although the better option would be to use a plugin for better control.

I haven't poked around much but here's something interesting from the [HTML Spec for Option](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#elementdef-option):

> The text IDL attribute, on getting, must return the result of
>   stripping and collapsing white space from the child text content of
>   the option element, in tree order, excluding any that are descendants
>   of descendants of the option element that are themselves script
>   elements in the HTML namespace or script elements in the SVG
>   namespace.

Basically means no way to put a newline or additional spacing inside a normal `<option>` element as that'll get truncated to just one. The layout hax were the only way I could get close to what I presume you wanted.

If anyone could elaborate on why the restrictions (and where they are mentioned) when it comes to `<select>` and `<option>`, I'd really appreciate it.